# How can i get State from my store in Appjs?

Tags: react-native, redux

I would like to see the state in my App.js
i am importing like this

```
import configureStore from './src/configureStore'
let store = configureStore()
```

so i am injecting in my App.js

```
<Provider store={store} theme={theme}>
  {console.log('11111',store)}
  <NavigationContainer>
```

in console only i can see this:
{dispatch: ƒ, subscribe: ƒ, getState: ƒ, replaceReducer: ƒ, @@observable: ƒ}

how can i see the state?

btw: configureStore is:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import Reducers from './reducers'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

export default function configureStore () {
    let store = createStore(Reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk))
    return store
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call [store.getState()](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate) method to get the current state tree of your application. It is equal to the last value returned by the store's reducer.

```
<Provider store={store} theme={theme}>
  {console.log('11111',store.getState())}
  <NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

for this u need Selector hook from "react-redux"

```js
...
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
...

...
const {yourStateKey} = useSelector((state) => state);
...
```

this part can be different based how manny store you have

```js
(state) => state
```

to set state value in store use "useDispatch" hook from "react-redux"

```js
...
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";
...
const dispatch = useDispatch();
...
dispatch(reduxActions.yourAction(yourValue))
```